# Routing components in React JS using login functionality

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to build a full stack web application using Spring and React JS.

I have created login/register APIs in Spring and have connected them to React. They work just alright.

This is my UserService

```
import axios from 'axios';

const user_base_url = "http://localhost:8080/users";

class UserService{

    createUser(user) {
        return axios.post(user_base_url + '/register', user);
    }

    authenticateUser(user) {
        return axios.post(user_base_url + '/login', user);
    }
}

export default new UserService();
```

This how I validate my user in the LoginComponent.

```
validateUser = () => {

        let user = { 

            username: this.state.email, 
            password: this.state.password,
        };
        
        UserService.authenticateUser(user).then((res) => {
            if(res.data === 'SUCCESS') {

                //logged in
                console.log("logged in");

            } else if(res.data === 'FAILURE') {
                console.log("NO");
                this.resetLoginForm();
                this.setState({"error":"Invalid username or password"});
            }
        })
    };
```

I now wish to add routes to my application so that certain components can only be accessed when logged in.

```
function App() {


  return (

    <div>
      <Router>
          <HeaderComponent/>
          <div className="container">
            <Switch> 
              <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPageComponent}></Route>
              <Route path ="/customers" component = {ListCustomerComponent}></Route>
              <Route path ="/add-customer/:id" component = {CreateCustomerComponent}></Route>
              <Route path = "/view-customer/:id" component = {ViewCustomerComponent}></Route>
              <Route path = "/admin-login" component = {AdminLoginComponent}></Route>
              <Route path = "/admin-register" component = {AdminResgisterComponent}></Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
          <FooterComponent/>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
} 

export default App;
```

How can this be achieved? I found solutions using tokens but I haven't used a token, I only check user is entering correct username and password from the database (MySQL) via my REST API.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to use jwt tokens in backend. Then send those token when user logged in to the system. After that you can save that token in local storage in frontend. Finally  you can create router guards by checking the token from local storage.

Comment: Yes but I wanted to know if there is any alternative to jwt tokens.

Comment: It depends on how you protect you API endpoints. Maybe it is basic auth, maybe you use session id. In any case the idea is to store that "secret" part of your login result in the browser (sessionstorage, indexeddb, memory) and use some mechanism in React to check it before rendering a component. And then before calling your API you just fetch necessary details from storage.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Routes that are usually defined: Open Routes and Protected Routes.
Open Routes are the ones that are accessible by a user without any authentication and Protected Routes are the ones that require a certain form of authentication to be accessed.

Now, let's proceed to answer your questions.

## How to Implement a Protected Route?

First, you need to know whether the user is authenticated or not and for the same, you will need to use a certain "value" or "token" (Like An ID Card) that says that this user is authenticated.
For a simple practise application, you could just store a `Boolean` saying whether the user is authenticated or not.

You will need to store this value in a place such as Local Storage, Cookies or Session Storage.

For this example, I have assumed that you are storing the value in a local Storage.

A Protected Route will be wrapped around with a condition that checks the Local Storage to find a value that says the user is authenticated.

- isAuthenticated === true ===> Show The Desired Component.
- isAuthenticated === false ===> Redirect the User to the login page.

```
// isAuthenticated is extracted from the local storage.

<Route path="/aClassfiedPath" render={() => (
    isAuthenticated === true
      ? <DesiredComponent />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
```

You will also notice another practice, that is, to make a totally separate Layout for the Protected Components and inside the Layout, check whether the user is authenticated or not.

```
// Assuming the required Modules have been imported

const ProtectedLayout = ({children}) => {
if (!isAuthenticated) {
  return (
    <Redirect to="/loginPage" />
  )
}

// children contains the Desired Component and `div` tag represents a custom
// container meant for Protected Routes. Like: A Speacial Header or Side Navigation.

return (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
)
}
```

## Recommended Read

- [An Article on Protected Routes](https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-protected-routes-authentication/)
- [`<Redirect>` Reference](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)
- [Render Prop of `<Route>`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func)